# Tate's thesis integrating over the p-adics

Tags: integration, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, p-adic-number-theory, zeta-functions

Okay im trying to integrate the following over the padic numbers to get an euler factor for the completed riemann zeta function

$\int_{Q^x_{p}} 1_{Z^x_{p}} |x|^s d^xx$

where $d^xx$ is with respect to the multiplicative Haar Measure on the p-adics.  It seems that when I integrate with respect to the multiplicative Haar Measure I don't get the correct result.  Howver if I use the additive Haar measure I do get the desired result.  But in his thesis Tate uses the multiplicative group.  Here are my steps

$\int_{Q_{p}} 1_{Z^x_{p}} |x|^s d^xx = \int_{Z^x_{p}} |x|^s d^xx$

Then i split $Z^x_p$ into a disjoint union of products $p^n$ and $u \in Z^*_p$

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \int_{p^n{Z_{p}}} |p^n u|^s \frac{du}{|p^n u|}$

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \int_{p^n{Z_{p}}} |p^n|^{s-1} du$

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} p^{-n(s-1)}$

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (\frac{1}{p^{s-1}})^n$

$\frac{1}{1-p^{s-1}}$

As you can see I get something similair to the euler factor but not quite there, and if I was to use the additive measure we would get the desired result.  I think it is an issue with the scaling of $Z_p$ with the multiplicative measure but i can not pinpoint the error.  Thanks for any help I can get.

Comment: The normalized Haar measure on $Z_p^\times$ is $ \mu(a+p^n Z_p) = p^{n-1} / (p-1)$ for for $a\in Z_p^\times$. The Haar measure on $Q_p^\times$ is $ \mu(b(a+p^n Z_p))= p^{n-1} / (p-1)$

Comment: @reuns does this measure give me the desired result for the integral?  If it does i'm still doing something incorrectly.

Comment: nvm I figured it out thank you